# Finding time difference

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to execute the following query in MS Access to find difference between two times. The time format is, eg, start time 8:00 and end time 14:00. But I get error in the query, please help me to fix it.

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Date] DateTime;

SELECT
    M.CompanyID AS Emp_ID,
    MIN(H.EventTime) AS Attending,
    MAX(H.EventTime) AS Leaving,
    Format( (Leaving-Attending), "hh:mm:ss") AS TotalHrs
FROM
    Member AS M
    LEFT JOIN History AS H ON M.UserID = H.EventUserID 
    AND
    ( Format( [EventDate], "dd/mm/yyyy" ) ) = [Enter Date]    
WHERE
    companyId NOT IN (select companyid from exceptions)
GROUP BY
    M.CompanyID, EventDate
ORDER BY
    CompanyId;
```

Ayha

Comment: see these http://allenbrowne.com/casu-13.html ;  http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1641804-query-calculate-difference-between-two-times.html  ;  http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-date-or-time-values-HP001098486.aspx

Comment: just in TotalHrs field "#Error# is displayed

Comment: Maybe try `Format( (MAX(H.EventTime)-MIN(H.EventTime)), "hh:mm:ss")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move most of that `SELECT` into a subquery.  Then from the parent query you can use the names defined in the subquery, `Leaving` and `Attending`, when you compute their difference.

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Date] DateTime;
SELECT
    sub.Emp_ID,
    sub.Attending,
    sub.Leaving,
    Format((sub.Leaving - sub.Attending), "hh:mm:ss") AS TotalHrs
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            M.CompanyID AS Emp_ID,
            MIN(H.EventTime) AS Attending,
            MAX(H.EventTime) AS Leaving
        FROM
            Member AS M
            LEFT JOIN History AS H
            ON
                M.UserID = H.EventUserID 
            AND Format([EventDate], "dd/mm/yyyy") = [Enter Date]    
        WHERE
            M.companyId NOT IN (select companyid from exceptions)
        GROUP BY
            M.CompanyID, EventDate
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY sub.Emp_ID
```

Most of the heavy lifting is done within the subquery.  The parent query simply retrieves subquery values and subtracts a pair of values, so this suggestion should not impose a significant additional performance penalty.

Comment: @HandsUp, I tried but I am getting an error "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is mispelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

Comment: Sorry, I had a comma after `MAX(H.EventTime) AS Leaving`.  Remove that as in the revised answer.

Comment: I copied the join unchanged from your original query.  You reported a different error for that query, but must be Access only complained about the first error it found.  Take a copy of your original query, discard the `TotalHrs` expression from the `SELECT` fields list, and get the join working correctly.  Once you've done that, you can apply that same join in the subquery I suggested.

Comment: The query still returns Error in the TotalHrs field. –

Comment: Can you get a temporary version to work if you discard the `TotHrs` field?

Comment: All other fields like attending and leavings get filled with correct result except the difference with error. Even without discarding the totalhrs, I get the other results.

Comment: I understood the problem we are trying to solve is *"JOIN Expression not Supported"*.  So if you now have a version of the query which does not throw that error, compare the `FROM` clause in that version to the `FROM` clause in the answer I suggested.  They must be different somehow.

Comment: Sorry. I already solved the JOIN expression problem but posted the comment in a wrong place. My commented posted earlier regarding the JOIN... "after adding braces in the beginning and end it works. No error now. (M.UserID = H.EventUserID AND Format([EventDate], "dd/mm/yyyy") = [Enter Date])"

Answer (score 2):

Leaving and Attending do not have values until the query has been completed.  Therefore, Leaving-Attending means nothing to Jet while it's processing the SELECT part of a query.  You will need to substitute MIN(H.EventTime) for Attending and MAX(H.EventTime) for Leaving in the calculation for TotalHrs.